# trying to convert a comma delimited string to a list struts2 jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I'm learning ognl and struts2.  I'm trying to create a list that I can use to find items.  Generating a list from String.split which is wrapped in Arrays.asList.  see below for
jsp.  Am I doing this right, will struts2 support all of the ognl spec ?

thanks much!

```
 <s:set var="names" value='%{Arrays.asList(shipments[index].name.split(","))}' />

later in the page I test...

<s:if test="%{shipmentName in #name} ">
```

Comment: Why dont you split the string in Action class and send the List to jsp just to show it?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  But shouldn't the ognl work ?

Comment: @Rick Probably, but that isn't logic you should be doing in the view anyway. In your `<s:if>` you're referencing `name` whereas you set `names`, which would also be a problem.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for reviewing my issue. you're right, that was a problem.